# c# - combine 2 statements in a catch block into one

Tags: c#, exception

Does anybody know if it's possible to write the code in the catch block below as a single statement?  I haven't been able to come up with a way, and was just curious if there was one.

IMPORTANT: the stack trace must be preserved.

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e is MyCustomException)
        {
            // throw original exception
            throw;
        }

        // create custom exception
        MyCustomException e2 =
            new MyCustomException(
                "An error occurred performing the calculation.", e);
        throw e2;
    }
```

Comment: I think that's about as good as you're going to get. You could catch MyCustomException first, and just include a throw. That's perhaps more standard, but still requires two "logic blocks"

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't wan't to catch and then throw the more specific exception (MyCustomException) in a separate catch? e.g: catch (MyCustomException) { throw } catch (Exception e) { ... }

Comment: @Dexter - The reason is because the exception may already be MyCustomException.  If it is, then I don't want to wrap it again in another MyCustomException, I just want to rethrow it, but making sure to preserve the stack trace.

Comment: @dcp - Dexter's solution, using `catch (MyCustomException) { throw; }` wouldn't re-wrap and should preserve the stack.  That is a good answer.

Comment: @antik - Please re-read the original post. The question was whether it was possible to write the code in the catch block *as a single statement*, not how to write the existing code more elegantly. I agree it's a good answer, but it doesn't solve the original requirement. But I think it's as good as we can do here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about:

```
catch (MyCustomException)
{
   throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw new MyCustomException(ex);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that will work, but it's still 2 statements (just across separate catch blocks).

Comment: Isn't this begging the question?

Comment: However, it looks much nicer than the other ones do. And code length is not the only thing you should pay attention to.

Comment: Agreed, but this code has already been mentioned in the comments to the original question. Maybe just a disagreement in how SO is supposed to work, but a response that answers a different question may not be the most helpful. The question is, "Is it possible to write the code in the catch block below as a single statement?" The answer is, "No." </grinch>

Comment: @Dave - I don't know what you mean by "begging the question". The challenge was to write the code in the catch block in a single statement (please refer to the original post)
@winSharp93 - Again, I was just trying to see if there was a way to write it as a single statement.  Code length isn't the only thing I'm paying attention to, it was just a "is it possible" question.

Comment: @dcp: my "begging the question" comment was to the answer, not your comment. :)

Comment: @Dave - oops, my apologies :)

Comment: >> Agreed, but this code has already been mentioned in the comments to the original question
Sorry - I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   if (e is MyCustomException) throw;

   throw new MyCustomException("An error occurred performing the calculation.", e);
}
```

I think that's about as terse as it gets, I think.

This immediately throws `MyCustomException` up the stack (which is what you're accomplishing with `throw;` in your question) while throwing a `MyCustomException` to wrap other `Exception` types encountered in execution.

Alternatively, you can just do:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   throw new MyCustomException("An error occurred performing the calculation.", e);
}
```

and in the case where `MyCustomException` was caught, you'll have a `MyCustomException` in `e.InnerException` where is `e` a `MyCustomException` at the next level of the stack OR you'll have a `System.Exception` in the cases that `MyCustomException` is not what was caught.

Comment: `throw e;` would reset the stack.

Comment: No, if Exception is already MyCustomException, then you will double wrap it, so you end up with MyCustomException with an inner exception of MyCustomException.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this isn't answering your original question, however its worth noting that you should be careful when using `throw` - although miles better than `throw ex`, there may still be circumstances where using `throw` does not preserve the stack trace. See:

http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2008/01/02/rethrowing-exceptions-and-preserving-the-full-call-stack-trace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible.

However, the stacktrace will contain additional entries:

```
public static class ExceptionHelper
{
    public static void Wrap<TException>(Action action, Func<Exception, TException> exceptionCallback)
        where TException : Exception
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (TException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw exceptionCallback(ex);
        }
    }
}
//Usage:
ExceptionHelper.Wrap(() => this.Foo(), inner => new MyCustomException("Message", inner));
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e.GetType() == typeof(MyCustomException) ? e : new MyCustomException("An error occurred performing the calculation.", e);
        }
```

Comment: `throw e` is not equivalent to `throw`

Comment: Good point!  I don't know if this can be done in a single line of code then, although I have no idea why this would be required anyway, unless it was more of an academic question than an actual requirement.